# A concrete example of an orthonormal basis of a Hilbert module over $K(H)$, the algebra of compact operators

Tags: modules, banach-algebras

Suppose $H$ be a Hilbert space, $K(H)$ be the set of compact operators on $H$, $E$ be Hilbert module over $K(H)$ and $(e_{\lambda})_{\lambda \in I}$ be a orthonormal bass for $E$,

Can you mention example for  $H,  K(H),  E$ $\hspace{0.1cm}$ and $(e_{\lambda})_{\lambda \in I}$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you take any finite-dimensional Hilbert space $H$ and $E=K(H)$. Then $E$ is just the algebra of matrices $M_n$ with $n=\dim H$. The standard matrix units in $M_n$ certainly form an orthonormal basis.